# Double quotes in Apache POI setCellFormula

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache POI 3.10.1 (Java) I have an issue with POI replacing double quotes in a String with ". Excel cannot read this as it expects real double-quotes.

This:

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(A2=\"TEST\";1;2)");
```

Becomes this in the sheet1.xml (opening the text.xlsx (as a zip) and looking in sheet1.xml):

```
<f>IF(A2=&quot;TEST&quot;;1;2)</f>
```

Excel throws an error about errors in the sheet. Writing the formula in Excel, I can see from the XML that it expects this:

```
<f>IF(A2="TEST";1;2)</f>
```

I cannot seem to find anybody that has had a similar issue. Does anybody know if this is a bug or me doing something wrong?

Comment: Changing `"` into `&quote;` is something normally done by the XML library, at a lower level than Apache POI. Have you tried with other JVMs / other XML libraries / etc?

Comment: No, I am constrained by the JVM on the platform and regarding libs I am just using Apache POI and the libs that it depend on. But I cannot imagine not being able to use double quotes in a formula. Somebody must have encountered that issue before me.

Comment: Apache POI has a large number of unit tests, including of formulas, and given those all pass there's a chance that it's your environment...

Comment: Does anyone know if POI uses disable-output-escaping="yes" when creating the formula in the XML (zipped xlsx)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is due to semicolon

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(A2=\"TEST\",1,2)");
```

This worked to me.

See the [online help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) for details of the if-function and how to provide parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found simillar issue in my project some time ago.

In my case I was not able to predict chars in raport that will be added to XML and then to PDF/MSExcel.

I used CDATA (import org.jdom.CDATA) funcionality:

```
final Element xmlIssueTitle = new Element(xmlMessageIssueTitle);
final CDATA xmlIssueTitleCDATA = new CDATA(issueObj.getTitle());
xmlIssueTitle.addContent(xmlIssueTitleCDATA);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, but cell.setCellFormula takes a String as arguemnt and not a CDATA Object, so I am constrained to using a String.

Comment: Try to add [toString()](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/CDATA.html). How you get your *String*? Did you read it from file?

Comment: I have tried all kinds of things. The lowest I think we can get to proving that it does not work is this:
cell.setCellFormula("IF(A2=\"TEST\";1;2)");

I mean - you cannot do a "IF(A2=\"TEST\";1;2)".toString() because it's not an object. I did also try this:
cell.setCellFormula(new String("IF(A2=\"TEST\";1;2)"));

Comment: Where you store that MSExcel formula? Do you hardcode if in Java or use some file to read it? Try with reading external property file that will store those formulas and read it as a "String".

Comment: Yeah, I am actually reading it from a properties file, but it's the same result regardless of where the String() comes from. So yes, I ended up trying to hard code it to eliminate issues with String encoding or other things that could disturb. So I thought that creating a one-line example would maybe get somebody to try it to see if they can replicate the issue.